# Exporting template class from a module without using partitions

Tags: c++, templates, module, c++20

I want to export a template class from a module, in a way that it'll be completely useable ("visible") to those who use the class. The only requirement is that the class definition won't be at the same file with the primary interface unit.

The first thing I tried to do is:

```
//Module.ixx
export module Module;
export template<typename T> class SomeClass;

//SomeClass.hpp
template<typename T>
class SomeClass { };
```

But then I couldn't have used SomeClass because of its incomplete definition, which makes sense because I export only a declaration.

So, if I must export the class itself (because its a template I can't even export just a header or something) it means that I must use "export" when I define the class, and that means I must use partitions:

```
//Module.ixx
export module Module;
export import :SomeClass;

//SomeClass.ixx
export module Module:SomeClass;
export template<typename T>
class SomeClass { };
```

Is this really the only way? It feels pretty strange to use partitions just to export things correctly, when I have no intent to use the partitions directly in any other place.

Comment: "*when I have no intent to use the partitions directly in any other place*" I don't know; maybe you *should* have such an intent.

Comment: Why is it a requirement that “the class definition won’t be at the same file”?